# Compiling .m files that call simulink models

Tags: matlab, simulink, mcc

Will a .m file that calls a simulink model using `sim()` sill compile and function properly using `mcc`?

Alternatively would compiling the simulink files to a dll, calling that dll from the .m file and then using `mcc` produce the desired results?

Comment: Did you try this? Easy way to find out.

Comment: @Adriaan valid point, I just don't want to pay for the matlab compiler unless I have to.

Comment: Oh, you haven't bought the compiler yet? In that case, seems like a proper question to email TMW before buying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sim` function is **not** supported by `MATLAB Compiler`.

There are a couple of workarounds, although they are messy and require quite a bit of modification to your workflow.  See [simulink matlab standalone executable unable to get output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41964437/simulink-matlab-standalone-executable-unable-to-get-output/41965175#41965175) for more info.